# Compare with null, not working in java

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have been trying to compare with `null` in if condition but it's not working and always goes in Else. Following is the code,

```
String authEmail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("AUTHOR_EMAIL"));
Log.i(gtag, "author email => " + authEmail);
    if (authEmail == null ) {
        Log.i(gtag, "in author check - IF NULL");
     } else {
            Log.i(gtag, "in author check - ELSE ");                 
     }
```

Here `cursor` is the result of querying SQLite database and `AUTHOR_EMAIL` is name of column. Logcat shows author email as null but still it goes in ELSE. Following is the Logcat:

```
06-24 15:30:55.307: I/GCA-Abs-Con(1282): author email => foo@bar.de
06-24 15:30:55.307: I/GCA-Abs-Con(1282): in author check - ELSE 
06-24 15:30:55.357: I/GCA-Abs-Con(1282): author email => null
06-24 15:30:55.357: I/GCA-Abs-Con(1282): in author check - ELSE
```

3rd line of logcat shows `authorEmail` is `null` but still it goes in `else`.

**I tried `authEmail.equals(null)` as well, but that didn't work too.**

**How should I modify the if condition to check for null perfectly ?** 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try 

  if(authEmail.equals(null));{
   
  }

Comment: it seams authEmail is a string "null" instead of Null Object

Comment: No, you don't use `equals` for null checks.

Comment: Tried equals as well, but didn't work

Comment: @chrylis as null is String OP must use `equals`

Comment: Inside that `else` clause, try adding `authEmail.getClass()` to the log output.

Comment: @ShumailMohy-ud-Din you need "null" as String not null as object (without double quote)

Comment: It seems like authEmail is the string "null", not the value null. As the answers below suggest, do an equals. I would suggest DarkDusts answer, as his answer won't cause any NullPointerExceptions

Comment: What's wrong with Question ? 4 down votes - :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check whether a database field has the SQL NULL value, use the cursor's [isNull](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#isNull%28int%29) method:

```
int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("AUTHOR_EMAIL");
if (cursor.isNull(index)) {
    ...
} else {
    String authEmail = cursor.getString(index);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did it - actually, that was most immediate solution.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
  if (authEmail.equals("null")) {
```

instead of

```
  if (authEmail == null ) {
```

Used `.equals()` for string comparison

Comment: i think `authEmail.equals(null)` must be `authEmail.equals("null")`

Comment: My Java is rusty, but don't you get an exception if `authEmail` is `null` and you thus try to call a method on `null`?

Comment: Thanks! I tried authEmail.equals(null) but that didn't work but when i tried authEmail.equals("null"), it worked  ! Is it because `null` here is to be treated as value ?

Comment: @ShumailMohy-ud-Din exactly you added null

Comment: +1 - but if you don't mind kindly explain the concept for `null` and `"null"`

Comment: @ShumailMohy-ud-Din `"null"` means Value to be null and simple `null` means Object to be null

Comment: and also, it would be better checking for `"null".equals(authEmail)`

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
if (authEmail == null || authEmail.equals("null")) {
    ...
}
```

This first checks whether the variable is null. If it's not, it checks whether string is the text `null`. Of course, it's better to trace why the string can contain the text `null` which looks unintentional.

Comment: I tried authEmail.equals(null) but that didn't work but when i tried authEmail.equals("null"), it worked  ! Is it because `null` here is to be treated as value ?

Comment: No, it is because the variable does contain a text. And that text happens to be `null`. As in `String text = "null";`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
if (authEmail == null || authEmail.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
  // handle null case
} else {
  // handle other case
}
```